# Is it possible to use the Facebook mobile SDKs for only mobile app install ads?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile, ads

I am not currently using Facebook's Android SDK in my Android app, and I only want to integrate it enough to capture installs via Facebook Mobile App Install Ads.

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/) describes the need to "[c]omplete your Basic page under App Settings." If I enter my app's package name--and only its package name--I get an error:

> You have specified Package Name, but you did not specify Class Name. Launching a native Android application requires both.

I don't want or need my app to be launched, do I? I only want to track conversion rates of ad clicks to app installs (and runs). The only way I can get the **Promote** link to show up on the left is to supply values for **Class Name** and **Key Hash** and set **Facebook Login** to **Enabled**. Is this really necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is necessary to fill out those basic details to use our SDK, however, those fields are only used for login authentication via fb - which is the most popular use case for our SDK.  Your app will not be launched or anything like that if you supply those fields.  For your case, just fill them out and leave it as is and you will be able to run ads without worrying about anything else.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse. I'm testing the `publishInstall` method. The method returned `true`, but the "Last Mobile Install Reported" field hasn't been updated. Does it typically take awhile for it to reflect the last install reported?

Comment: For me, they didn't show up when I tried reporting installs from the emulator, they only started showing up once I had published the app in Google Play.

Comment: I can't answer for sure, but @Twilite's answer sounds correct.

Comment: Allright. I published the app update that includes the Facebook SDK method call to `publishInstall`, installed the update from Google Play Store, ran the app, and checked the "Last Mobile Install Reported" field--no change. It's been about ten minutes. I confirmed that I'm using the correct app ID. Where do I go from here?

Comment: I don't think updates are considered as an "install".  What if you tried uninstalling and installing your app again?

Comment: Sorry about not clarifying that, Jesse. That's what I did--uninstalled the app, then installed cleanly from the Play Store.

Comment: I spoke with some others and they said that if you filled out all the necessary requirements on the dashboard and you integrated our SDK correctly, then it should work.  Otherwise it is an error on your part that needs to be fixed.  Make sure you have the correct package name, class name, key hash, basic info and logo all filled out on your dashboard settings.  Also, please ensure that your publishInstall code is 100% confirmed that it is called when an user first launches the app.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse. I hadn't realized those fields needed valid values as you mentioned they're only used for login authentication. I have corrected this, and it _seems_ to be working, but I don't seem to have any way of knowing whether the reported installs are from Android or iOS. Is there any way to break that down?

Comment: No problem Jeremy, if this answer helped you please remember to accept it so other people find it useful.  In terms of seeing the breakdown between android and iOS I believe that isn't possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The API requires these fields. Although in my experience it doesn't launch your app. It is merely used for the credentials in the development side of the Facebook integration in www.developer.facebook.com

Hope that helps.

RF